# Ehcache at class level and query not getting synced

Tags: spring, jpa, caching, ehcache

My Cache configuration for class Employee in XMl

```
 <cache name="com.model.Employee"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="100" overflowToDisk="false" statistics="true" />

<cache name="employees" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" overflowToDisk="false" timeToLiveSeconds="60" statistics="true" />
```

Using query cache, to fetch the employees

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"), @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value="employees")})
    List<Employee> findAll();
```

Two applications use the same database for example A & B,If A application delete the employee Id 8 , but at the same time application B maybe using this cached id of 8.

With the current configuration the employee object in application B may get null.

Any tips to resolve this , or to improve the current configuration

Answer (score 1):

That's the concept of a cache. You have two choices:

- Like with a little stale value (and configure expiration for how stale you support)
- Evict from cache when a value become stale

From very far in my memory, Hibernate is doing that by default. But that might have change. They will evict from cache all queries related to a table that was updated. Anyway, that's the kind of behaviour you seem to want.

But then, you are talking about two applications. If I assume that are not sharing their cache, then... they should. Otherwise you can't evict from the cache of the other application. So you need to Ehcache cache communication/replication.